# Is there a way to bulk delete records

Tags: 2013, delete

It seems that I have a a lot of duplicated records in my " central " area so I wanted to either filter by Area then delete the duplicates if there is a way to do that or bulk delete every record that is "Central" in the Area column.. is that possible?

Comment: sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerShell for doing this

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sitecollectionURL") 
$web = $site.rootweb 
$list = $web.Lists["Name of the List"]

$caml='<Where>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="Area" />
            <Value Type="Text">Central</Value>
        </Contains>
    </Where>'

$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$query.Query=$caml | Write-Output

$items=$list.GetItems($query) 
$listItemsTotal = $items.Count;

for($x=$listItemsTotal-1;$x -ge 0; $x--)
{
        $items[$x].Delete()
}

$web.Dispose() 
$site.Dispose()
```

Another option is to use the view itself. First filter the list items, then select the items to delete using the (tick) option. Then click on delete from ribbon.

[image]

Comment: how would I do this I never used powershell.

Comment: You can save this as a PS1 file into your sharepoint server. Then open SharePoint Management Shell. Run that PS1 file by typing the full path. You should change the site collection URL, list name as well as the Area column name.. Also I updated answer on how to do this using the UI.

Comment: AMAL, the highest access I have to this sharepoint site is Site Collection Administration ... I don't have access to the server. Will the powershell option not work for me then???

Comment: Also, the 2nd option I was thinking about that but there is 15000 records I need to delete and it is only allowing me to choose 100 at a time.. is there a way around that?

Comment: Probably you can export to excel, then make the changes and sync it back.

Comment: how would I sync it back?

Comment: Sorry you cant sync, rather you should delete the existing list and create new list based on the excel file.

Comment: If I delete the list wouldn't all of my columns be deleted as well?

Comment: Yes. But you can get it created automatically using the excel file. I would suggest you try this in test environment before doing it on Production.